# Convert txt file to dataframe in R

Tags: r

is there a way to convert txt file data into Dataframe in R

For example,
I have a df.txt file in my project folder

df.csv

```
"a" "e" "b" "c" "d" "f"
a 1 e 1 b1 c1 d1 f1
"a" "e" "b" "c" "d" "f"
a1 e1 sdf c1 d1 f1
"a" "e" "b" "c" "d" "f"
a1 e1 sdf sdf d1 f1
"a" "e" "b" "c" "d" "f" "z"
a2 e1 b1 c1 d1 f1 z1
```

expected output

```
    a    e    b    c    d    f    z   ### column names

    a 1  e 1  b1   c1   d1   f1   NA
    a1   e1   sdf  c1   d1   f1   NA
    a1   e1   sdf  sdf  d1   f1   NA
    a2   e1   b1   c1   d1   f1   z1
```

Comment: Asking if there's a way to read a CSV file in R is aking to asking if fish swims :) .

Comment: I asked if there is a way to convert the contents in csv to dataframe in R :)

Comment: your csv doesn't look like a valid csv to me.

Comment: Edited. Sorry it is a txt file

Comment: See `read.csv`, `read.table` and `read.csv2` documentation. ie, from the interpreter: `?read.csv`. You will be able to read in that file with `read.csv`, but you won't get the desired output, because your "header" rows will be treated as ordinary rows. You will need to massage the resulting data.frame into what you need.

Comment: Your other option is to just drop all the headers except the top one from the file itself first.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this.

```
z <- gsub('\"', '', readLines('df.csv', 8))
z <- strsplit(z, ' ')
z <- lapply(z, `length<-`, max(lengths(z)))

Map(\(x, y) setNames(x, y), 
    z[seq_along(z) %% 2 == 0],
    z[length(z) - 1]
    ) |> do.call(what='rbind') |> as.data.frame()

#    a  e   b   c  d  f    z
# 1 a1 e1  b1  c1 d1 f1 <NA>
# 2 a1 e1 sdf  c1 d1 f1 <NA>
# 3 a1 e1 sdf sdf d1 f1 <NA>
# 4 a2 e1  b1  c1 d1 f1   z1
```

Comment: Great thanks. But if there are space in the values ````a 1````, the output does not come properly